# How many cores in Azure?

Tags: azure

I am trying to develop a C# ASP MVC app and use parallel processing. For testing I have a D1 Shared plan however I cant find anywhere how many cores I have access with this plan. Where can I find how many cores can I use in the app? Thank you!!

Comment: Why don't you look into the documentation of Windows Azure?

Comment: I was trying to find it however the only documentation that I found it was this https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google "azure d1 shared plan" - or look at [Azure App Service Pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/).

Bottom line, you are using a shared plan: the cores and RAM are shared - you have no guarantee to access. If you need a guarantee to the number of cores available, scale up to a Basic or Standard plan.

In a DEV/TEST subscription, the pricing differences are minimal and you can always scale up for testing and then scale back down - that's the power of the cloud :-).

Comment: a bit more details at: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans/

Answer (score 3):

Detail spec for all the plans, you can visit https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/

for share plan, you app is running on a share machine, potentially the spec of the VM might changed. but i guess the sandbox would limited your environment to 1 core.

as for parallelism, if your concerns is avoid spawning too many thread, you can use "Environment.ProcessorCount" as an indicator or just hard coded to a number. I would suggest you to have a hardcoded number and have this number in your config file.